# Admob ad sometimes plays when app loads

Tags: swift, admob

Sometimes I hear the audio from an ad when my app starts.  This is totally unwanted behavior.  Ads are only supposed to be presented at the end of a game, not on startup.  All of my ad-related code is below.  Can anyone spot a problem with it?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if NoAdsPurchased == false {
        print("Google Mobile Ads SDK version: \(GADRequest.sdkVersion())")
        if UseTestAdvertisements == true {
            self.interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID:"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
        } else {
            self.interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID:"ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX")
        }
        request = GADRequest()
        interstitial.loadRequest(request)
        interstitial.delegate = self
    }

}

func buttonActionGameOver(sender:UIButton) {

    if NoAdsPurchased == false {
        //Show ad
        self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
    }

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(temp:GADInterstitial) {
    print("diddismiss")
    if (NoAdsPurchased == false) {
        if UseTestAdvertisements == false {
            self.interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID:"ca-app-pub-4760046923514498/4070660162")
        } else {
            self.interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID:"ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX")
        }

    request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = ["2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"]
    interstitial.loadRequest(request)
    interstitial.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks fine. Are you sure your `buttonActionGameOver` button isn't being called anywhere else? Or, perhaps you're presenting the ad in your `interstitialDidLoad` delegate method?

Comment: Make sure you're using .isReady() before presentFromRootViewController. And make sure nothing else in the code is calling presentFromRootViewController.